# Setting Algolia index attributes with Laravel Scout

Tags: php, laravel, algolia

I am enjoying working with Laravel Scout and Algolia and I am able to index my content. (I am using the Algolia JS library to perform the searches).

However I want to get my facets for the search results but this needs to be done on the server side and I don't see how to this with scout. For example if I want to allow retrieval of the facets author and type I would like to set the following attribute on :

```
$index->setSettings(array("attributesForFaceting" => array("authors", "type")));
```

I would be fine doing it in  JS but somehow Algolia is highly suggesting to do this on the backend client - Laravel Scout for me:

> "please consider using a backend client to change the index settings"

Comment: The reason why Algolia is telling you to do this in your back-end is that you need an admin API key to set your settings. If you expose this in your front-end, anyone with access to the page could retrieve this API key and change your index. Which is why you should use your search API key in your front-end.

Comment: However, nothing prevents you to write a JS script that would use the admin API key and set the settings (and maybe index your data), on the condition that you keep this script private.

Comment: Another comment: "However I want to get my facets for the search results but this needs to be done on the server side" - You should set `attributesForFaceting` in your back-end, however the facets retrieval should be done in your front-end.

Comment: Thanks @Jerska. I understand the potential issue with the key and I created a new key with cusom ACL where I am allowing search and index settings rights through the API. With this I am able to set the index attributes through JS. That said Id rather do as you suggest and as algolia suggest, i.e. doing this on the backend. However I dont understand when this should be done, i.e. when should I set the attributes in the backend during the search lifecycle, especially since the search is sent and returned through JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not being familiar with Laravel Scout, I was only giving generic advice in the comments section :

- you should not expose an API key with other ACLs than search to your users
- settings in Algolia are usually set at the same time than data indexing

After looking into Laravel Scout, there is a [pending pull request from Algolia](https://github.com/laravel/scout/pull/19) to expose the `setSettings` method exactly to achieve what you're looking for.

In the meantime, you can probably extend the `AlgoliaEngine` trait to add this method on your own, or just have a small script on the side to set those settings.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I will work on extending AlgoliaEngine so that I can set the attributes for the index. That should work until there is an updated version of scout.